# Struts2 : Interceptor is being only one time instead of two times

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

I am working on Struts2 Interceptors .
I have read that Struts2 Interceptors are just like Filters , which execute before the Action class is executed and one more time after processing the result ( Please correct me if i am wrong )  , that is two times

But when i ran the below code , the interceptors are executed only once .
Please correct me if i made any mistake .
Please see my code below :

**This is My Struts.xml file**

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="test" extends="struts-default">
<interceptors>
 <interceptor name="loginkiran" class="vaannila.MyLoginInterCeptor" />
</interceptors>
        <action name="HelloWorld" class="vaannila.HelloWorld" method="kiran">
            <interceptor-ref name="loginkiran" />
            <result name="SUCCESS">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**This is my Action class**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public HelloWorld() {
    }
    public String kiran() {
        System.out.println("iNSIDE THE aCTION CLASS");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

**This is my Interceptor class**

```
public class MyLoginInterCeptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Destroying Interceptor");

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext
                .getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);

        System.out.println("iNSIDE THE iNTERCEPTOR");

        return invocation.invoke();

    }

}
```

**This is my JSP File :**

```
<html>
<body>
<%
System.out.println("iNSIde THE jsp");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Output for the above code is this :**

```
iNSIDE THE iNTERCEPTOR
iNSIDE THE aCTION CLASS
iNSIde THE jsp
```

Answer (score 3):

Interceptors are not executed twice (nor are filters): interceptors (and filters) *wrap* the action (or servlet/etc.)

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Before action invocation...");
    return invocation.invoke();
    System.out.println("After action invocation...");
}
```

Comment: Thanks David , actually i follwed a tutorial which stated that they will be executed twice , please see this image of that tutorial http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/struts2.jpg/   and please correct me if i misunderstood

Comment: I already did correct you; the image doesn't directly state they're executed twice--it's ambiguous, and doesn't accurately represent the nested nature of intercepted, nor does it indicate that an interceptor isn't done executing until the action has completed. (Unless normal flow is interrupted, of course.)